# Trying to use react-native-sensor-manager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, null

i wrote this code correctly like it is in Documentation :

```
SensorManager.startProximity(100);
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('Proximity', function (data) {
  /**
  * data.isNear: [Boolean] A flag representing whether something is near the screen.
  * data.value: [Number] The raw value returned by the sensor (usually distance in cm).
  * data.maxRange: [Number] The maximum range of the sensor.
  **/
});
SensorManager.stopProximity();
```

But i got an error TypeError:null is not an object(evaluating 'SensorManager.startProximity');
Can You Help me ?